# How to reset forgotten mac os password

Tags: macos, mac

My Mac automatically login with the administrator user but i don't remember the password to login using SSH.

How can i reset the password?

I have no AppleID and the recovery console and the resetpassword terminal command is not working... Command not found.

Comment: Are you running `resetpassword` from recovery (command + R on boot)? Please update question with macOS version and whether you have FireVault encryption enabled.

Comment: I tried to run resetpassword from regular terminal... The Command+R nor working... I am not sure about the version but its 3 years old... Maybe lion or something

Comment: Did you try to reset it in Single User mode?  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/61905/how-can-i-reset-a-macs-password-from-single-user-mode

Answer (score 0):

If you can't get the recovery partition to boot, you'll need to make a bootable USB drive and boot from that.  https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372

You can't reset the password from a regular terminal, you have to boot into some other OS.

Note:  You will lose your keychain...